# What is the purpose of Social Security and Medicare deductions from my paycheck?

Tags: united-states, 401k, social-security, payroll-taxes

Sorry, this might be a basic question, but I'm having trouble understanding this, so would like to ask here.

I've recently started a full-time position, and I notice that two things are being deducted from my salary in addition to income taxes:

1. Social Security
2. Medicare

I had adjusted my income / expenses and factored in taxes, but these two have thrown my calculations off.

I know that these two are mandatory, but what is their function? When do I get to "collect" on Social Security and Medicare?

I'm very clear about 401K now, but I've deferred putting money into my 401K till I get a hang of the other deductions on my salary.

Comment: Doesn't your 401(k) offer a match?

Comment: As @JoeTaxpayer hints -- if your employer matches 401(k) contributions, that's "free money" you're giving up by deferring getting into the plan. Delaying that deduction, and delaying taking advantage of the employee stock purchase plan, which was also "almost free money" though it made calculating tax returns ugly, are the two financial decisions I most wish I could go back and fix. I understand that you want to understand what your cashflow will look like and figure out how much you can spare -- but the earlier you can make yourself get into the 401(k), the better. At least get the match!

Comment: I understand the importance of the 401K - I just hadn't factored in SS tax or medicare in my calculations, so am re-evaluating it. One other (related) question I should have asked: if social security / medicare covers my retirement, why do I need a 401K (though I realize that might be a separate question).

Comment: Since no one has answered it, but it isn't a full answer I will just comment here. **When do I get to "collect" on Social Security and Medicare?** You likely won't collect SS unless you retire at age 62/65 in the next 20 years. [The SSA trust fund](http://www.ssa.gov/oact/trsum/) will be depleted by 2034. To eliminate the shortfall, they will either need to increase the 15% payroll tax you pay or reduce your benefits when you reach retirement age.

Comment: @user1873 - Or find other ways to fund it.  It's not like it *has* to run in in isolation.

Comment: @Bobson, it's not like we will be able to [fund much of anything in 2035](http://www.cbo.gov/publication/43288). Total debt will exceed 200% of GDP, combined interest payments and SSA increases will ballon to +$800 billion in today's dollars. Where/Who you going to take it from?

Comment: @user1873 - I refuse to speculate on what will happen in 20 years.  20 years ago, the debt was on its way down as a percentage of GDP, after having climbed for the 20 years before that, and fallen for the 20 years before *that*.  What makes you think it won't turn around again in the next 20 years?

Comment: @Bobson, I don't think Congress has the intestinal fortitude to [increase taxes](http://www.cbo.gov/sites/default/files/cbofiles/attachments/45471-Long-TermBudgetOutlook_7-29.pdf) by $465 billion (14%) or cuts spending (13%) by that much over the next 25 years. Not when the sequester, a 2% reduction in the increase in baseline spending, ($40-$80 billion over 10 years) was [so tough](http://money.cnn.com/2013/10/18/news/economy/sequester-economy-shutdown/). **Do you think Congress could pas a cut 10x larger? (Or at least 3.3x larger)**

Comment: @user1873 - Neither raising taxes nor reducing spending is required for the Debt **vs GDP** number to change.  GDP could also increase.  But there’s a ton of other things that could happen - the European economy collapsing, for instance.  But this is not on topic on this SE - we’re not on Politics.SE, and we’ve gone rather far astray from the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These two items (social security and taxes) should have also been withheld from any other positions you held previously.

Both these items cover you in the future. Social security when you reach retirement age, or earlier if you are disabled. Medicare to serve a your health insurance when you are a senior citizen.

Everybody who has wage income pays the medicare tax, there is no maximum limit. For Social security you pay your share until your wage income hits a specific limit. Both Social security and medicare are split between the employee and the employer. If you are a contractor you get to pay both parts.

The rate and limits are set by congressional law, and they can be adjusted by congress. In terms of financial crisis they have actually lowered the rates to help workers.

The [social security website](http://www.ssa.gov/planners/maxtax.htm) gives you the limits for each year:

> For 2013, the maximum amount of taxable earnings was $113,700. In
>   2014, the maximum amount of taxable earnings is $117,000.

If you want to be able to track your earnings and benefits go the the [social security  website to see where you stand](http://www.socialsecurity.gov/myaccount/). Keep in mind that the it will only have your earnings through the previous year.

Comment: So it's effectively a [regressive tax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regressive_tax)?

Comment: I wanted to keep politics out of the answer.

Comment: I was not aware that was a political question.  Is it?

Comment: @gerrit It doesn't seem political to me, it is in fact a regressive tax, the more you make, the less you pay.

Comment: FICA is not withheld from student employees at schools. It's entirely conceivable previous employment would not have had these taxes withheld. http://www.irs.gov/Charities-&-Non-Profits/Student-Exception-to-FICA-Tax

Comment: @gerrit Social Security is a progressive tax in the sense that the less you make the more you get out of it. "For people with lower than average earnings, the
ratio of the lifetime benefits they receive from Social
Security to the lifetime payroll taxes they pay for the
program is higher than it is for people with higher
average earnings." Here's the long version from the Congressional Budget Office. https://www.cbo.gov/sites/default/files/cbofiles/ftpdocs/77xx/doc7705/12-15-progressivity-ss.pdf

Comment: @Schwern - That's not what the definition of "progressive tax" is.  See [here](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/progressivetax.asp) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_tax).  It is a progressive *program*, in the sense that the less you pay into it the more you get out of it (which is what your link addresses), but the *tax* part of it is purely regressive.

Comment: "Both these items cover you in the future."  It's more realistic to say that these items cover seniors (and other eligible parties) *now*.  By paying social security now you are earning credits toward receiving benefits later.  The dollars for those benefits will come from the taxpayers of the future.

Comment: Just to clarify: "Social security you pay your share until your wage income hits a specific limit." This sentence could be construed to mean that when your income passes a certain point you no longer pay social security taxes. The truth -- and what I presume the writer meant -- is that there is a cap on tax: You pay a percentage of the first $100,000 or so of income (the limit changes every year). After that you still pay tax, you just don't pay additional tax on the additional income. Note that your benefits are also capped, so it's not like the rich are getting a free ride.

Comment: Ditto "the more you make the less you pay". No. The more you make the more you pay, up to a limit. For people whose incomes are over that limit, it would be accurate to say that they pay a smaller PERCENTAGE of their total income. For example, for 2014 the maximum tax is about $14,400. If you make $144,000, that's 10% of your income. If you make $288,000, that's only 5% of your income. If you make $1,440,000, it's only 1% of your income. But it's the same number of dollars.

Comment: "I wanted to keep politics out of the answer." So if you say, "This is a program that guarantees every American a comfortable retirement income" that's a non-political answer, but if you discuss where the money comes from and where it goes, that's political? i.e. if you repeat the stated goals of a government program, that's non-political, but if you discuss how it actually works, that's political? Propaganda is non-political but facts are political? Seems backwards to me.

Comment: @gerrit, since there isn't a cap on the taxes paid, but a cap on income subject to tax, the answer is officially "no" based solely on the definition of regressive tax. I realize the distinction is small, but it does exist. And per previous discussion on this answer, this is where I exit this comment.

Answer (score 13):

From [Socialsecurity.gov](http://www.socialsecurity.gov/medicare/) on Medicare:

> Medicare is our country’s health insurance program for people age 65
>   or older. Certain people younger than age 65 can qualify for Medicare,
>   too, including those who have disabilities and those who have
>   permanent kidney failure.

From [Socialsecurity.gov](http://www.socialsecurity.gov/retirement/about.htm#a0=0) on Social Security:

> You can apply online for retirement benefits or benefits as a spouse
>   if you:
>
> - are at least 61 years and 9 months old;
> - are not currently receiving benefits on your own Social Security record;
> - have not already applied for retirement benefits; and
> - want your benefits to start no more than 4 months in the future. (We cannot process your application if you apply for benefits more
>     than 4 months in advance.)

Course the rules may change over time so these are just the current information from those sites.

From [the IRS site](http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Understanding-Employment-Taxes) on one other point that may be useful here:

> Social Security and Medicare Taxes
>
> Employers generally must withhold part of social security and Medicare
>   taxes from employees' wages and you pay a matching amount yourself. To
>   figure out how much tax to withhold, use the employee’s Form W-4 and
>   the methods described in  Publication 15, Employer's Tax Guide and
>   Publication 15-A, Employer's Supplemental Tax Guide.